# How to get the signed hex value?

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I want to know how to get the product value of signed hex value.

Given

```
a = 0x7FBDB2
b = 0x06F8C
results = hex(a * b)
print(results)

# RESULTS
0x37a91beb58

but the expected results is 0x1FFE31BEB58
```

What is the best way to get this signed value?

Comment: What makes you think the result is incorrect?

Comment: the results is in unsigned hex. What i want is how to get the results of 0x1FFE31BEB58 (unsigned hex). What is the best way to do this. for you to have this results you need to two's complement `a` then multiply it with `b` then two's complement the product.

Comment: Already get the answer, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Python variables are set to unsigned, for you to have the results of signed variable. First you need to convert the variables to two's complement (NOTE: having 0 as MSB(left most number of binary digits) means you don't need to undergo two's complement) then start your operations. If the results' MSB is not 0 you need two's complement it.

Comment: Python integers are unbounded. The concept of MSB makes little sense without a fixed bitwidth. (Or alternatively, you could consider that the MSB of *any* positive integer is always 1.) What do you mean by "Python variables are set to unsigned". Python integers represent both negative and nonnegative quantities.